# Install MySQL Community Server 5.7 via bash shell script in CentOS 7 (x64)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, centos, installation

I am trying to create a bash shell script to automate the installation of MySQL Community Server version 5.7 on CentOS 7 (x64).

I came across this lovely script https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh and put together the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATADIR="/var/lib/mysql"
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$(pwmake 128)"

echo ' -> Removing previous mysql installation';
systemctl stop mysqld.service && yum remove -y mysql-community-server && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && rm -rf /var/log/mysqld.log

echo ' -> Installing mysql database server';
yum localinstall -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
yum install -y mysql-community-server

echo ' -> Creating mysql data directory'
mkdir -p "$DATADIR"
chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"

echo ' -> Initializing mysql database'
mysqld --initialize-insecure=on --user=mysql --datadir="$DATADIR"
mysqld --user=mysql --datadir="$DATADIR" --skip-networking & pid="$!"
mysql=( mysql --protocol=socket -uroot )
for i in {30..0}; do
    if echo 'SELECT 1' | "${mysql[@]}" &> /dev/null; then
        break
    fi
    echo 'MySQL init process in progress ...'
    sleep 1
done
if [ "$i" = 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 'MySQL init process failed'
    exit 1
fi

echo ' -> Setting mysql server root password';
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | "${mysql[@]}" mysql
"${mysql[@]}" <<-EOSQL
    SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
    DELETE FROM mysql.user where user != 'mysql.sys';
    CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
EOSQL
if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
    mysql+=( -p"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" )
fi
if ! kill -s TERM "$pid" || ! wait "$pid"; then
    echo >&2 'MySQL init process failed.'
    exit 1
fi
chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"

echo " -> Mysql server setup completed, your root password: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
```

The script is supposed to do the following:

1. Removing previous mysql installation
2. Installing mysql database server
3. Creating mysql data directory & set ownership
4. Initializing mysql database
5. Setting mysql server root password

When I ran the script, this is the output I've got:

```
Total download size: 142 M
Installed size: 652 M
Downloading packages:
mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                       | 142 MB  00:00:04     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                               1/1 
  Verifying  : mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                               1/1 

Installed:
  mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.10-1.el7                                                                                                                                                                                              

Complete!
 -> Creating mysql data directory
 -> Initializing mysql database
MySQL init process in progress ...
MySQL init process in progress ...
...snipped...
MySQL init process in progress ...
MySQL init process in progress ...
MySQL init process failed
```

I thought the steps in the script were pretty straight forward, yet it failed. Any ideas why it might be?

Comment: I started to work on this method of installation because the standard way of installation yielded the following error (after a clean install and service start) `[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.` (discussed here: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69)

Comment: Remove `&> /dev/null` to see more. This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: After removing that, I see the following: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
MySQL init process in progress ...`

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to achieve this by re-writing the shell script. This now works flawlessly for me :)

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqlRootPass="$(pwmake 128)"

echo ' -> Removing previous mysql server installation'
systemctl stop mysqld.service && yum remove -y mysql-community-server && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && rm -rf /var/log/mysqld.log && rm -rf /etc/my.cnf

echo ' -> Installing mysql server (community edition)'
yum localinstall -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
yum install -y mysql-community-server

echo ' -> Starting mysql server (first run)'
systemctl enable mysqld.service
systemctl start mysqld.service
tempRootDBPass="`grep 'temporary.*root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //'`"

echo ' -> Setting up new mysql server root password'
systemctl stop mysqld.service
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*logfile*
wget -O /etc/my.cnf "https://my-site.com/downloads/mysql/512MB.cnf"
systemctl start mysqld.service
mysqladmin -u root --password="$tempRootDBPass" password "$mysqlRootPass"
mysql -u root --password="$mysqlRootPass" -e <<-EOSQL
    DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test; 
    DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%'; 
    DELETE FROM mysql.user where user != 'mysql.sys'; 
    CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${mysqlRootPass}';
    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOSQL
systemctl status mysqld.service
echo " -> MySQL server installation completed, root password: $mysqlRootPass";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'First step : Disabling and removing partially MariaDB'
yum remove MariaDB-common MariaDB-compat MariaDB-server
yum repolist enabled | grep "mariadb.*"

echo 'Removing Percona' 
yum remove Percona-Server-client-55 Percona-Server-server-55   
Percona-    Server-shared-55.i686 percona-release

echo 'Last step : Removing completely mariadb' 
yum remove mariadb mariadb-server

echo 'Removing mysql'
rm /etc/my.cnf
yum remove mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-devel mysql

echo 'Installing mysql assuming the rpm file is already download'
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
yum install mysql-community-server

echo 'Starting mysql' 
systemctl enable mysqld
systemctl start mysqld

echo 'Finally the root password needed for mysql to start'
echo 'oldpass will contain the temporary password value'
echo 'newpass must be written here and must meet Mysql Password Policies'
oldpass=$( grep 'temporary.*root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | 
        tail -n 1 |  sed 's/.*root@localhost: //' )
newpass="Password!" 
mysqladmin -u root --password=${oldpass} password $newpass
```